# Mapbox edit or delete point in dataset

Tags: data, mapbox

I am using mapbox:///mapbox.mapbox-terrain-v1,mapbox.mapbox-streets-v5 for the style of my map. But I need to change the Persian Gulf to Arabian Gulf. How can I edit or delete the Persian Gulf to Arabian Gulf? Is it possible to edit the dataset in Mapbox? Or only option for me is to provide my own dataset and style it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't edit Mapbox's tilesets. But you could:

- add a filter in your style to not show any point called "Persian Gulf"
- create a dataset with just one point, called "Arabian Gulf", and add that to your style.

Answer (score 3):

In this case, I followed Steve Bennett's advice of adding a filter or modifying the style. I added a filter to the water_label Persian Gulf and set the text-name property to the value I want.

```
[name='Persian Gulf'] {
    text-name: "'Arabian Gulf'";
}
```

Comment: Nice one! Even better.